# Handle all exceptions in Flask route

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators, endpoint

I have a simple route in my Flask app:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def homepage():
    return '{}'.format(1 / 0)
```

When the user visits site.com/ she should see the result of 1/0. Of course that's not possible, so Python throws me an error.

Now, I would like all errors across all my endpoints to be handled in a special way: I would like them to return a JSON response, like:

```
{
    'status_code': 500,
    'status': 'Internal Server Error'
}
```

I wrote a decorator to do exactly this:

```
def return_500_if_errors(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            response = {
                'status_code': 500,
                'status': 'Internal Server Error'
            }
            return flask.jsonify(response), 500
    return wrapper
```

I then added the decorator to the endpoint:

```
@return_500_if_errors
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def homepage():
    return '{}'.format.(1 / 0)
```

However, the decorator seems to have no effect.

Comment: Order of decorator matters

Comment: @YiFei I tried to invert the order, same result.

Comment: Care to post the inverted code? I just tried myself and your decorator works with no problem. Note exactly how Joost use the decorator. @app.route must be the outmost.

Comment: @YiFei I feel pretty bad because I was sure I'd tried to change the decorators order. However, I tried again today and you were indeed right - it works. Sorry for the misleading information!

Comment: why not use flask's error handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by both @YiFei and @Joost, the issue was with the decorators order.

This does indeed work:

```
def return_500_if_errors(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            response = {
                'status_code': 500,
                'status': 'Internal Server Error'
            }
            return flask.jsonify(response), 500
    return wrapper

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@return_500_if_errors
def homepage():
    return '{}'.format.(1 / 0)
```

@Joost's answer is similar but somehow different as there it's the error itself to be captured and returned - rather than a standardized JSON.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend to use Flask's [error handler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/apierrors/#registering-an-error-handler) already existing decorator.

Basically, should look something like:

```
# flask will check if raised exception is of type 'SomeException' (or lower)
# if so, will just execute this method
@app.errorhandler(SomeException) 
def handle_error(error):
    response = jsonify(error.to_dict())
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    return response

# An exception will be raised, hopefully to be caught by 'handle_error'    
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def homepage():
    return '{}'.format.(1 / 0)
```

Just make sure the exception to be caught will have 'status_code' or put '500' if doesn't...

Comment: This has alredy being discussed, it doesn't quite give me what I need. See the edit history on @Joost's answer for more details.

Comment: Original link's dead. Here's the link to the latest Flask documentation for error handling: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/errorhandling/

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

def catch_custom_exception(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e), 500
    return decorated_function

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@catch_custom_exception
def homepage():
    return '{}'.format(1 / 0)

@app.route('/2', methods=['GET'])
def homepage2():
    return '{}'.format(1 / 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This may work but I'm not too fond of this approach. For example, what if I want to leave a few endpoints out? Also, do you know why the decorator approach doesn't work?